# Como fazer um Casting de outra Classe em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

boa tarde, estou começando agora a desenvolver em POO no PHP, e me deparei com um problema, preciso fazer com que uma variável de uma classe seja do tipo de outra, como posso fazer? Segue abaixo o modelo, estou tentando fazer isso, mas não deu certo:

```
private $dado1 = new Dado();
private $dado2 = new Dado();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não há como fazer isso explicitamente informando os tipos, pois o PHP usa tipagem dinâmica. Mas há um forçaçãozinha de barra na linguagem que te ajuda a mostrar pro PHP o que você pretende.

**Por Exemplo**

```
class JogoDeDados {
   /**
    * @var Dado Uma instancia de Dado
    */
   private $Dado1;

   /**
    * @var Dado Uma instancia de Dado
    */
   private $Dado2;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->Dado1 = new Dado();
      $this->Dado2 = new Dado();
   }

}
```

Quando você for utilizar a classe JogoDeDados, vai ser reconhecido com mais facilidade a semântica desses dois dados. Pelo menos pra mim, no Netbeans, isso é bem mapeado no projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Em PHP você não precisa colocar um tipo, você está apenas instanciando um Objeto mesmo. De certa forma, o tipo seria "Object". E aí você vai instanciar um objeto naquela variável.

O exemplo que o Luis deu acima está certo. Mas você tem que importar a classe na página.. se você estiver usando namespace, fica algo assim:

```
<?php 

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

namespace Caminho\Pasta; 

use Caminho\Pasta\Dado;

class JogoDeDados {

  private $Dado1;
  private $Dado2;

  public function __construct() {
     $this->Dado1 = new Dado();
     $this->Dado2 = new Dado();
  }

}
```

Ou então use "require" para buscar a localização da classe "Dado".

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível inicializar uma propriedade com um objeto diretamente na declaração da propriedade da classe, mas você pode fazer isso no construtor.

O recomendado é o construtor da sua classe requerer os objetos de dado necessários. Você pode forçar no type hinting to construtor da classe `JogoDeDados` o tipo desejado que você requer:

```
class JogoDeDados 
{

  private $dado1;
  private $dado2;

  public function __construct(Dado $dado1, Dado $dado2) {
     $this->dado1 = $dado1;
     $this->dado2 = $dado2;
  }

}
```

A vantagem dessa abordagem é que você pode alterar a instância de dado a ser utilizada sem precisar alterar seu `JogoDeDados`.

Se estiver utilizando PHP 7.4+, é possível garantir o tipo da propriedade:

```
class JogoDeDados 
{

  private Dado $dado1;
  private Dado $dado2;

  public function __construct(Dado $dado1, Dado $dado2) {
     $this->dado1 = $dado1;
     $this->dado2 = $dado2;
  }

}
```